# Wicket: how to dynamically add meta robots : noindex if URL contains the string "?wicket:"

Tags: java, seo, wicket, nofollow

Where would I start off with this?
I know how to add meta tags to the page, I guess Page#onBeforeRender is a good place to do so.
But: how do I determine whether the current URL containts "?wicket:"?

Calling

```
((WebRequest)getRequest()).getHttpServletRequest().getRequestURL()
```

only returns the part before the questionmark, and getPageParameters() returns null.

Thanks for inspiration in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah..... right again, I stumbled across the answer right after posting:

```
((WebRequest)getRequest()).getHttpServletRequest().getQueryString()
```

I am sorry for bothering you.